# Show a function is constant in its domain

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How can I show, using derivatives, that this function is constant in its domain?

$$
{\arctan(x)}+{\arccos \bigg(\frac x {(1+x^2)^\frac 1 2}\bigg)}
$$

Out of curiosity, is there another way without using derivatives as well?

Comment: Sorry if this sounds trivial, but you have to show that the derivative is $0$. Since the domain is an interval and since the function is differentiable on its domain, this is indeed equivalent to the function being constant.

Comment: You may find the following theorem helpful: If $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ for some $a<b$, then $f$ is constant on $(a,b)$. The proof of this theorem is an immediate application of the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Without Derivatives**

Suppose $\theta=\arctan(x)$. Then
$$
\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac{\tan(\theta)}{\sec(\theta)}=\sin(\theta)
$$
and
$$
\arccos(\sin(\theta))=\frac\pi2-\theta
$$
Thus,
$$
\arctan(x)+\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)=\theta+\frac\pi2-\theta=\frac\pi2
$$

---

**With Derivatives**
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\arctan(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)
&=-\frac1{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)^2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\\
&=-\sqrt{1+x^2}\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}^3}\\
&=-\frac1{1+x^2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\arctan(x)+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\arccos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)=\frac1{1+x^2}-\frac1{1+x^2}=0
$$

Comment: Very nice alternative, +1. Minor detail: if you say $\theta =\arctan x\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ instead of $\tan\theta=x$, this will justify the hidden $|\sec\theta|=\sec\theta$ and the arccos formula.

Comment: @julien: good idea. I changed it :-)

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate this answer :)